# Android Roboguice what is the purpose of extending a Robo Class?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, roboguice

i am new to roboguice
i have been looking at their documentations i get the idea
yes, instead of saying

```
 findViewById, i can just do @InjectView, etc
```

but what is the purpose of extending their classes, such as RoboAcitivy, or RoboFragment etc etc? i mean what is the benefit of that?  I still don't see it.

please helo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend you to look at [RoboActivity](https://code.google.com/p/roboguice/source/browse/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/activity/RoboActivity.java) class. Then, I think, it would be clear for you.

Roboguice is using annotations to know what and where to inject instances. This is done in `Injector` which must be invoked somewhere. Roboguice creators decided to run it in `Activity.onCreate()` method. Therefore `Activity` is extended to `RoboActivty` which adds to `onCreate()` code such this below:

```
final RoboInjector injector = RoboGuice.getInjector(this);    
injector.injectMembersWithoutViews(this);
```

Injector will detect annotated fields and inject instances.